# How can I use 'format_type' => 'custom' for a datetime field?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity with (among others) a field defined this way:

```
$fields['duedate'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Due Date'))
  ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'date')
  ->setDefaultValue(array(0 => array(
    'default_date_type' => 'now',
    'default_date' => '2050-12-31',
  )))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
  'type' => 'datetime_default',
  'settings' => [
    'format_type' => 'date_courte',
  ],
    'weight' => 5,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'weight' => 5,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

'date_courte' is a custom date format I created to display date as 'dd/mm/yyyy'. And it works!
I'd like to have the same result without using 'date_courte' so I tried

```
  'settings' => [
    'format_type' => 'custom',
    'format' => 'd/m/Y',
  ],
```

instead of

```
  'settings' => [
    'format_type' => 'date_courte',
  ],
```

And it doesn't work!

I'm pretty sure of `'format_type' => 'custom'`.
I think the problem comes from 'format' in `'format' => 'd/m/Y'`.

What should be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to use the `datetime_custom` display type vs `datetime_default`. You won't need to pass the `format_type` parameter in your settings array. You will end up with something like:

```
...
->setDisplayOptions('view', [
  'type' => 'datetime_custom',
  'settings' => [
    'date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
  ],
...
```

That should work how you'd like. The [datetime_custom formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21DateTimeCustomFormatter.php/class/DateTimeCustomFormatter/8.5.x) is defined in core's datetime module.